# Custom Windows installation and recovery partition with sysprep?

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-installation, sysprep

So I do know about the audit mode of Windows, sysprep.exe, and the Windows System Image Manager to create unattended answer files. I already used these tools to setup my new Windows 10 installation, in which I set the user folder to be on a normal HDD, and everything else on a SSD. Since a friend of mine requested a custom built PC, I thought I could do the same on his computer.

Just for personal interest, I wondered if I could setup the computer like a manufacturer does. Initlially I thought I could just install all drivers etc. in audit mode, and it would be fine... Well, except if someone decided to reset the system.

So is there a way to customize the recovery partition too? And by the way, what's the difference between Windows SIM and Windows ICD?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the `scanstate` tool of USMT tools and [follow the directions here in this Blog post](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/11769-create-provisioning-package-windows-10-a.html).

The directions are still valid as of today (meaning, merging the two big directories).

In addition, I don't install USMT on the machine I am setting up.  Instead, I:

1. download the USMT tools into a VM
2. copy/merge the two directories together into `c:\usmt\scanstate` as instructed in the link above
3. copy that merged `c:\usmt\scanstate` directory to the Windows 10 USB Boot stick I created, called "\drivers\recovery\usmt\scanstate"
4. setup a batch file that basically runs through the process outlined in the link above, all running from that USB stick (not even copying that USMT/Scanstate directory!  Just run it all from that USB stick when in Audit mode).

Has worked now for 4 machines.

The tricky part is you need to setup Windows 10 partitions as per "recommended" for a Recovery partition.  I can't find the link to the MSDN article at this time but basically you want to create the RECOVERY partition before the WINDOWS partition.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can set it so that when you reset the computer from inside Windows it uses a user-set .WIM file instead of a generic one. A reference for this is here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744280%28v=ws.10%29.aspx , however this applies for Windows 7. For Windows 8, maybe you could use the Windows ADK.